# Why uncalled template class members aren't instantiated?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I was wondering that when I create an instance of a class template with specifying the template type parameter.
**1)** why the non-called function do not get instatiated ? .
**2)** dont they get compiled until I try to use it ?
**3)** what is the logic behind this behavior ?

**Example**

```
template <class T>
class cat{
public:

T a;
void show(){
   cout << a[0];
}
void hello(){
   cout << "hello() get called \n";
}
}; 

int main(){
cat<int> ob1; // I know that show() did not get instatiated, otherwise I will get an    error since a is an int
ob1.hello();

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they instantiated the entire class, then you might get invalid code.

You don't always want that.

Why? Because in C++, it's *difficult* (and in some cases, outright impossible, as far as I know) to say, "only compile this code if X, Y, and Z are true".

For example, how would you say, "only my copy constructor if the embedded object can be copied"? As far as I know, you can't.

So they just made them not compile unless you actually call them.

Comment: is this just for class template or in any class in general,and if I dont use a function in a class template does this mean that the instance of this class template does not contain this function at all ?

Comment: @AlexDan: Only templates. Presumably, for regular classes, you already know everything about them, so there's nothing to prevent -- just don't include code that doesn't compile. For templates, though, you have no idea what they're going to be instantiated with, but you still want the ability to write normal code -- so the compiler helps you like this.

Comment: so by doing 'cat<int> ob1;' Im creating just member variable and non of the member functions is a member of the ob1 object yet.if this is correct, then does the compiler leave some memory inside ob1 object in case I call a function ? and also does the ob1 size change before and after I call a new function ? thanks a lot .

Comment: @AlexDan: Functions don't take up memory inside instantiations. :-) Only variables do.

Comment: ok that answers my 2nd and 3rd questions, what about the first one?

Comment: @AlexDan: Sorry, I can't tell which one are you referring to as the 'first one'. Would you mind copying the unanswered question here? Thanks.

Comment: by doing 'cat<int> ob1;' Im creating just member variables(a) and non of the member functions(hello and show) is a member of the ob1 object yet . is this correct ?

Comment: @AlexDan: Ah yes, that's correct. However, note that you can't really *test* this per se -- as soon as you mention the name 'hello', the compiler will look up that name and try to instantiate the template, if it's there. There's no way to tell C++ "give me all the members" without actually *mentioning* the name of the members you want, so this is somewhat transparent to you.

Comment: so in the example above the cat object will not be fully created until the end of the program, sothat it will know which function to include in the cat object and which not include. in this correct ? thanks a lot for your help really appreciate it. and sorry for the long discussion :)

Comment: @AlexDan: No worries. :-) Well, it depends on what you mean by "create". The *space* for it is allocated right where you instantiate it -- the member variables are already known. The *functions* aren't fully known until they're called, but their mere existence don't really affect any particular *instance* in any way.

Comment: @AlexDan: *object will not be fully created until the end of the program* -- not really, the type itself will be created when you create the first instance, each one of the member functions will be instantiated when it is (*odr-*)used. *When* the functions are actually compiled is a different issue, the details of which are not really relevant (translation of template functions happen as the last step before linking, after all non-template functions have been translated, but the *point of instantiation* is the appropriate place *before* the first *odr-use* of the function)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: does member functions of a class template "cat" (hello and show) are considered to be functions template. because it's the reason I can think of, that will make them get instatiated until they got called.and also when you said <i> "member functions will be instatiated when it is used "</i>, does it mean it becames a an instance of the class "cat<int>" or the object of cat<int> ob. (im little be confused bcz there is instance of class template and instance of type cat<int>).

Comment: @AlexDan: They *are* members of the class whether they are instantiated or not, but the compiler will not generate code. What I mean is that unless you *use* the function (*odr-use* in C++11) no code will be generated for the function. Consider those functions as *declared but not defined*. Also note that *member functions* are not part of each *instance* of the type, but rather shared.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas:so cat<int> has member variable a (which get compiled) and member functions hello and show (which don't get compiled inside cat<int> unless I attend to use them. otherwise they still there but not compiled). sothat when I try to use the member function hello by doing "ob.hello();" this will make the member function hello get compiled inside cat<int> and the object ob will be able to call the function hello. correct me if im wrong. and thanks a lot for mention that member function do belong to the class and they just get shared,this is the thing that I was missing :).

Comment: @AlexDan: member functions are never compiled *inside* the type, they are compiled *in the program*. Technically the function is not compiled *when* you use it but rather *if* you use it. The *when* is always when the compiler processes the Translation Unit. You are *always* able to call the function, and if you do so, the compiler will generate code for it.

Answer (score 6):

Templates aren't code - they're a pattern used to make the actual code. The template isn't complete until you supply the parameters so the code can't be made ahead of time. If you don't call a function with a particular set of template parameters, the code never gets generated.

Comment: Not 100% true, only for implicit instantiations. In explicit template instantiations all functions are generated (which means that it is a design decision not to do it always, and renders the answer only half true: it repeats the question statement without providing much of an explanation)

Answer (score 3):

To embellish a little more: this is typically called [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), and the bottom line is that it allows you to write "class patterns" of which *some* member functions may apply when instantiated with one template type, *other* members may apply when instantiated with a second template type, and by only requiring the ones you actually call to compile, you get to write a lot less code for operations that wind up being common ones.

By not requiring all member functions to be compiled you get all the niceties of static type checking on the functions that *actually are* compiled.

For example, imagine you had:

```
  template <typename E> 
  class myContainer {

      // Imagine that constructors, setup functions, etc. were here

      void sort();   // this function might make sense only if E has an operator< defined

      E max();   // compute the max element, again only makes sense with a operator<

      E getElement(int i);  // return the ith element

      E transmogrify();  // perhaps this operation only makes sense on vectors
  };
```

Then you have

```
  // sort() and getElement() makes total sense on this, but not transmogrify()
  myContainer<int> mci;         

  // sort and max might not be needed, but getElement() and transmogrify() might
  myContainer<vector<double>> mcvd;
```

Comment: i downvoted every answer and upvoted this one. finally one that doesnt claim that a nontemplate member function is a template

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: if the nontemplate member function is not a template. then how come it doesn't get instatiated until I use it ?

Comment: @AlexDan The distinction Johannes is making is that the *class* is the template and not the members functions, but that only the functions that are called are actually compiled.

Comment: @AlexDan Johannes is being a bit of a language lawyer, but he's correct.  In the C++03 standard section 14.5.1.1 paragraph 2 it says, "The template-arguments for a member function of a class template are determined by the template arguments
of the type of the object for which the member function is called."  Thus his statement that the member function is *not* a template.  Section 14.5.2 explains a little more about why he's making this distinction, i.e., you can have member functions that are templated separately from the class template.

Answer (score 2):

No code is generated for `cat<int>::show()` because you never call it. If you did call it you would get a compilation error.  Template functions which are never called do not exist.

Templates are little more than test substitution mechanisms.  This makes them very powerful.  You, as the programmer, may want to create a `cat<int>` knowing that you will never call `show()` or call anything else that would be invalid.  The compiler lets you know if you did, so it works out nicely.

So if your question is "why does it work this way", I would ask you "why not"?  It's a design choice.  This choice allows me to use a template type safely and still benefit from other parts of the code.  What's the harm?  You also generate less code, which is a good thing, right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP already knows this. The question clearly says "why".

Comment: @Mehrdad: I added a bit just now before I saw your comment.  I suppose I don't understand though; "why"?  Why not?  It's safe and allows me to do more as a programmer, so why artificially restrict the use of templates?

Comment: @Mehrdad:  The answer to any "Why?" question in language design is "Because the designers decided so."   Difficult choices must be made in designs, and there often is no clearly unambiguous reason why they went one way or the other.

Comment: @abelenky: Language designers don't toss coins to make decisions (as far as I know :P). There's quite often a good reason behind their decisions. Especially for a language like C++.

Comment: @EdS.: It's *not* to avoid imposing "artificial restrictions". Otherwise, the compiler would compile *everything* lazily, and you'd never find out if you had typos unless the code was actually called.

Comment: @Mehrdad: How so?  restricting this use case would seem artificial to me as there is no reason to do so.

Comment: @EdS.: I'm saying, if your reasoning was correct, then it would apply outside of templates too.

Comment: @EdS. in normal a normal class, when I instantiate an object of this class I already now that all the members get created too. so what I dont understand is does this apply also to class template and does the member function show is a member of the ob1 object before I try to call it. thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Well, ok, I thought a discussion regarding templates only was assumed here. Yes, you're right; anything I said is specific to templates only.

Comment: @EdS.: Yes, your thought was correct. I'm just saying, your *reasoning* has nothing to do with the fact that these are templates. If they were the reasons behind the design of the language, then they would've applied to ordinary classes too.

Comment: @AlexDan: Each call to `cat<T>` generates a new class depending on `T`, i.e., one for each `T`.  The same is true for member functions; code for a given function `cat<T>::func` is only generated if it is called. So no, `cat<T>::show()` does not exist in your final executable.  This is only true for template types.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Outside of templates, functions must be compiled because there is no way to know whether they will be called or not, and the users may not actually have the code (so they can't be compiled on the spot).  But with templates, it's different, because the user *does* have the code, *always*.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Uh, no, that's completely incorrect. It's actually quite obvious if they're needed to be compiled -- because you tell the linker to export their symbols, either through the command line or through some mechanism like `__declspec(dllexport)` (in the case of a library), or your `main` method refers to them somehow, directly or indirectly (in the case of an executable).

Comment: Er, replace "linker" with "compiler", my bad.

Comment: @Mehrdad: What are you talking about?  I can compile a file with a bunch of functions in it with `g++ -c foo.cpp`.  I can then delete my source file, create a new source file where I call some of those functions, but not others.  Then link the two together.  The compiler had to compile all the functions in the first file because it had no idea which ones I would use.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Have you ever tried doing the same thing with template declarations, instead of regular declarations? And you have never gotten an error for a missing template definition? Where did the compiler get the code from? o.O

Comment: @Mehrdad: Compiling a file full of uninstantiated templates?  I may have at one time, why?  What would be the point?  It wouldn't be compiling anything.  The definitions still need to be included in the file where you actually instantiate them.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: No, I'm talking about where you **call** the templates. You said the "user *does* have the code, *always*" but I'm telling you that's just true except when it's not. Just because you're using templates doesn't mean the user will have its source code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13186/discussion-between-benjamin-lindley-and-mehrdad)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I'm busy right now, sorry. :( I just check for notifications every so often haha.

Comment: @Mehrdad: That's fine, I'm on my way to work now, but when you have time, I would appreciate a clarification, I believe the chatrooms stay open indefinitely.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Sure, I'll try to drop by sometime. Feel free to @ me if I forget. (Damn, I wish SO had a "mark as unread" feature.)