# Why uncalled template class members *parameters* ARE instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

This question is a counterpoint to: [Why uncalled template class members aren't instantiated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252378/why-uncalled-template-class-members-arent-instantiated), where the author was surprised that some template methods weren't instantiated.

I have the opposite problem: parts of my function are getting instantiated when I don't expect them to.  Take the following program:

```
template <class T> class Foo;

template <class T>
class Bar {
  template <class U> void Baz(typename Foo<T>::X x) {}
};

int main() {
  Bar<int> bar;
}
```

This program fails to compile with the error:

```
test.cc:6:40: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'Foo<int>'
  template <class U> void Baz(typename Foo<T>::X x) {}
                                       ^
test.cc:10:12: note: in instantiation of template class 'Bar<int>' requested here
  Bar<int> bar;
           ^
test.cc:2:26: note: template is declared here
template <class T> class Foo;
```

But why is it trying to instantiate a parameter of a function I haven't called?  It's a template function with a template parameter that it cannot know, which makes it doubly weird that it instantiates the function argument type.

Why does it do this?  And why does SFINAE not help me here, and at worst remove the overload from consideration?

Comment: As one data point, if the function did not have the `::X` dependent type, and was only `void Baz(Foo<T> x)`, this would compile without attempting to instantiate `Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

When you create an instance of a template class, the class needs to be fully defined. This includes the member function declarations. If one of the member function declarations are not fully defined, then the class itself is not fully defined.

In this case, there's no definition for `Foo<T>::X` so the `Baz` function can not be fully declared, and the class as a whole is not fully defined.

Comment: An instance of a template class does not need all of its members to be defined. Try `template <typename T> struct S { void f() { T t = 0; } void g() { } }; int main() { S<void>().g(); }`, which compiles and runs without a problem, but by your logic should not.

Comment: Change 'definitions' to 'declarations' in the second and third sentences, and this answer becomes correct.

Comment: This doesn't really explain what makes a function parameter different than the function body (the question I linked shows that what you said is NOT true for function *bodies*).  It also doesn't explain why SFINAE doesn't work here.

Comment: @hvd The `S` structure is not only fully defined by itself, its member functions are fully declared as well. While `S::f` can't be called because of using the type `void` it's still fully declared.

Comment: @JoshHaberman I've changed wording of the answer, as per the tip of Chris Dodd.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Right. That isn't what you wrote in your original answer, but your edited version looks correct to me.